# Kafka Streams | RocksDB exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Using kafka version is 2.7.0 for application

Try with kafka stream maven version 2.2.1 kafka stream in pom.xml , then stream is started and getting expected output.

But when updating to maven version 2.3.0(or above) in pom.xml, then  getting below error from logs and stream is not starting

```
Exception in thread "Average-3ded0155-d697-492b-897b-4da5bfec5cf1-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error opening store KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000005 at location /kafka/Average/statedir/Average/1_0/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000005
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBTimestampedStore.openRocksDB(RocksDBTimestampedStore.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:253)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:54)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$init$1(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:103)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:209)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:473)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:728)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:625)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:553)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:512)
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Column family not found: keyValueWithTimestamp
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:306)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBTimestampedStore.openRocksDB(RocksDBTimestampedStore.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error/root cause when I include "kafka-streams" and "rocksdbjni" as dependencies in my pom.xml file. After removing the later one, the error vanishes. My aim was to create a jar file with dependencies and use it in a docker container. I included "rocksdbjni" since some dependency errors occured during the development. Finaly I found out that they originated from the used docker image and not from the pom.xml.

```
Exception in thread "streams-window-sum6-b7f79924-c195-428f-bc02-c7d61d7a0f7d-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error opening store aggregate-state-store1.1606723200000 at location /tmp/kafka-streams/streams-window-sum6/0_0/aggregate-state-store1/aggregate-state-store1.1606723200000
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.put(MeteredWindowStore.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractReadWriteDecorator$WindowStoreReadWriteDecorator.put(AbstractReadWriteDecorator.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamWindowAggregate$KStreamWindowAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamWindowAggregate.java:147)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:96)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1033)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:690)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error opening store aggregate-state-store1.1606723200000 at location /tmp/kafka-streams/streams-window-sum6/0_0/aggregate-state-store1/aggregate-state-store1.1606723200000
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBTimestampedStore.openRocksDB(RocksDBTimestampedStore.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegment.openDB(TimestampedSegment.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegments.getOrCreateSegment(TimestampedSegments.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.TimestampedSegments.getOrCreateSegment(TimestampedSegments.java:25)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractSegments.getOrCreateSegmentIfLive(AbstractSegments.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:102)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.lambda$put$2(MeteredWindowStore.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.put(MeteredWindowStore.java:126)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Column family not found: keyValueWithTimestamp
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBTimestampedStore.openRocksDB(RocksDBTimestampedStore.java:75)
    ... 29 more
```

Here is my pom.xml file based on the official documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/tutorial) which works with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=myapps.MyClass` as well as with the jar `java -cp app.jar myapps.MyClass`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>streams.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>streams.examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Kafka Streams Quickstart :: Java</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!--
        Execute "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar"
        to build a jar file out of this project!
    -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <!-- This filter is to workaround the problem caused by included signed jars.
                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
                                -->
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>myapps.MyClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Kafka dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? I use also a local version of `rocksdbjni` for Mac M1 support.